# 100°C = 100 K =?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, units, unit-conversion

I'm in first year. Our class is in lesson " Heat and Thermodynamics". While solving a numerical problem of a reversible engine he told us that 100 degree Celsius is equal to 100 kelvin. I inquired but could not get satisfactory answer. Pleas help me understand it.

Here is the numerical, please consider it: A reversibe engine works between two temperatures whose difference is 100c. If it absorbs 746J of heat from the source and rejects 546J to the sink, calculate the temperature of the source and the sink. Ans (100°C, 0°C)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about physics.

Comment: If it is an absolute temperature, this is simply wrong.  A *temperature difference* in Kelvin and degrees centigrade will have the same *numeric value*, though.  But in any case, this question is not about programming and off-topic on this site, sorry.

Comment: Can't it be that you confuse between temperature, and difference of temperature? Tell us how you did your calculus.

Comment: @Sofia: I don't think calculus is needed for this problem.

Comment: @KyleKanos - "calculus" is a non-English speaker's word for "calculation".

Answer (score 6):

The important part is that it works "between two temperatures whose difference is 100°C". Celsius and Kelvin are not the same, but their degrees measure the same.
You can see that by direct substitution $T(ºC)=T(K)+273.15$

therefore

$T_2(ºC)-T_1(ºC)=T_2(K)+273.15 -(T_1(K)+273.15)=T_2(K)-T_1(K)$

Comment: You mean that the difference is 100 whether you take Celsius scale or Kelvin scale? Right?

Comment: yes, because the 'size' of one degree is the same in both, but they start in different places, 273.15 degrees appart. the difference of 2 temperatures doesn't depend in any way on where the scale starts, so in this case they would be 100 degrees appart

Comment: Well, there's really two "kinds" of °C.  An "affine" kind and a "relative" kind.  The "affine" kind is the usual notion of temperature where 0 °C = 32 °F = 273.15 K.  These are numbers on a scale with an absolute origin.  The relative kind is what you get when you take the difference of two affine temperatures.  The notation is confusing here, but I have seen the relative version written as Δ°C to distinguish it (though not always).  In that case you basically have 1 Δ°C = 1 ΔK = 9/5 Δ°F

Answer (score 4):

A difference in degrees Celsius is equal to one in degrees Kelvin.
So 150 K - 100 K = 50 K = 50 C = 423.15 C - 373.15 C.

The absolute values cannot be compared without taking the 273.15 offset into account.

Comment: In other words, 1 degC in magnitude is the same as 1 degK in magnitude, but 0 degC is still 273.15 degK in absolute terms

Comment: To put it yet another way, if your temperature changes by 0 C it doesn't change by 273K or 32 F.

Answer (score 0):

What your instructor has said is right. While taking Temperature differences (delta T), etc. we take x Celcius = x Kelvin, so we can take any delta T value in Celcius in our numericals interchangeably.